# Independence and pairwise independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X, Y, Z$ are independent random variables which are equal to 0 with probability 1/2, and 1 with probability 1/2. Are the events ${X = Y }, {Y = Z}$ and ${X = Z}$ pairwise independent? Are they independent?

Just to check:

I got that the events are pairwise independent but not independent.

Pairwise independent: $P(X=Y)=P(X=0)*P(Y=0)+P(X=1)*P(Y=1) = 1/2$
similarly, for Y=Z and X=Z, and their compliments are all 1/2

Not independent: $P(X=Y=Z) = 1/4$ ,however $P(X=Y)P(Y=Z)P(X=Z) = 1/8$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: *"Suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables"* suggests they are independent (and pairwise independent)

Comment: You are not showing pairwise independence of the events $A=(Y=Z)$, $B=(Z=X)$ and $C=(X=Y)$. To do that, one must show, for example, that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Re the independence, indeed one must compute $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, but this is not $1/2$.

Comment: but that does not mean that events X=Y,Y=Z and X=Z are pairwise independent, even though, the random variables are independent? am I not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: @Did ok take A = (Y=Z) and C=(X=Y), then their intersection is event (X=Z). The probability of this event is again 1/2. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, $A\cap C$ is not $(X=Z)$.

Comment: P(A∩B∩C)=1/4? Is that correct?

Comment: I happen to think there is everything in my comments needed to correct your post and to make you reach a solution. They contain specific points to that effect, but, true, not  fully detailed ready-to-be-handed-back answers. If you find this intolerable, well, so be it.

Comment: @Did I am not asking for fully detailed answers. Simply saying that A intersect C = is not (X=Z) does not help in understanding why it isn't. On the other hand, showing A intersect C = is not (X=Z) because [your explanation of why it is wrong] is much more insightful and helpful than simply saying it's wrong. It gives no help or insight into the problem or feedback at what I should be doing to correct.

Comment: @Did and I am only saying it since I believe this will help others as well when you post your comments on other threads

Comment: Sure--but there is a moment when one comes to wonder why anybody aware that $A=(Y=Z)$ and $C=(X=Y)$ is unable to realize that the assertion that $A\cap C=(X=Z)$ is absurd. So, yes, communication in mathematics is based on a whole set of assumptions about the knowledge of the person you communicate with, and yes, if these assumptions are not met, things become much more difficult. Now, if you want to excommunicate me because I consider, say, that the sentence "Let $p$ denote a prime number greater than $10$ then $p=2k+1$ for some integer $k$" requires no further explanation, please do so.

Comment: just to clarify what I meant by "X=Z" is as the answer below reasoned "if both X=Y and Y=Z occur then surely X=Z does too". And I am not trying to excommunicate anyone, only trying to receive appropriate help and feedback. That's why I asked to clarify in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The test for *Pairwise Independence* is whether: $\mathsf P(X{=}Y , Y{=}Z) \mathop{=}^? \mathsf P(X{=}Y)\mathsf P(Y{=}Z)$ and likewise for the other two combinations by symmetry.

The test for *Mutual Independence* is whether: $\mathsf P(X{=}Y , Y{=}Z, X{=}Z) \mathop{=}^? \mathsf P(X{=}Y)\mathsf P(Y{=}Z)\mathsf P(X{=}Z)$

---

Noting that: $\{X{=}Y\} \cap \{Y{=}Z\} \equiv \{X{=}Y\} \cap \{Y{=}Z\} \cap \{X{=}Z\}$ so clearly at least one of the above will not hold.   But which?

Well, you've shown that $\mathsf P(X{=}Y)=\mathsf P(X{=}Z)=\mathsf P(Y{=}Z) = \frac 1 2$ and that $\mathsf P(X{=}Y{=}Z) = \tfrac 1 4 $, so its the former and not the latter.   As you correctly reasoned.

---

Alternatively, we can argue *for* pairwise independence by claiming that when given any value of $Y$, then whether the events $X{=}Y$ and $Y{=}Z$ will then occur is determined by values of $X$ and $Z$, which are independent random variables.   Thus any pairs of the events are independent. (By symmetry.)

We can argue *against* mutual independence by noting that if we know that if any two of the events both occur, then the third event must surely also occur.   That is, if both $X{=}Y$ and $Y{=}Z$ occur then surely $X{=}Z$ does too.   Indeed, we may only have either exactly one of the events occurs, or all three events occur.   Thus they are clearly not mutually independent events.

Confirming your result.

Comment: The test for mutual independence is, **in addition to the tests for pairwise independence**, whether: $\mathsf P(X=Y , Y=Z, X=Z) \mathop{=}^? \mathsf P(X=Y)\mathsf P(Y=Z)\mathsf P(X=Z)$.

Comment: "Alternatively, we can argue for pairwise independence by claiming that when given any value of Y, then whether the events X=Y and Y=Z will then occur is determined by values of X and Z, which are independent random variables." The trouble with this reasoning is that it would show the desired independence when (X,Y,Z) are i.i.d. nonsymmetric Bernoulli although the events (X=Y) and (Y=Z) are then non independent.